# Playing large, 360 video files (4gb+), on Oculus Go, using Unity3D VideoPlayer

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ffmpeg

I am using unity [VideoPlayer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html) to play 360 degree video files. Its all working wonderfully and I can build to Oculus Go and Quest without issue.

The problem is that if the video file exceeds a file size of a little more than 4 GB then, once built, it wont play the file.

Now this, to me, is odd behavior. The Oculus Go will play the video file if it is simply added to the gallery and played, telling me that the Oculus Go is capable of playing the file. I am a bit lost as to what to look at with this and how to go about fixing it. The 4GB file size limit reminded of the [fat3d file size limit](https://wiki.vuze.com/w/FAT32_file_size_limit). But I'm unsure if this is related or not since it can play the video in the gallery.

Thus far I have solved the problem by using FFMPEG to reduce the constant rate factor and thus quality of the video to get under the limit as this was hardly noticeable in the quality and reduced the file size significantly. The problem is that some videos are quite long and it seems that I actually need some of them to be approx 5 GB.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Your videos are external files, right? They are not bundled assets?

Comment: Any solution for this problem? getting the same problem with the native player